# WPF C# Circle Progress Bar WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, system.drawing, windowsformshost

So I'm getting a weird error... I followed some steps to create a CircularProgressBar in my WPF C# App. It works fine on my desktop, it doesn't on my laptop.

I create a WindowsFormsHost and make the Circular Progress Bar the Child. I then make it the children of a grid called ProgressGrid.

Anyway, The error just says "Unhandled exception has occured in a component in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error" It runs perfectly fine if I click continue mind you.

The error details say "System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid" it goes on to list pretty much everything I wrote. I thought it had something to do with Dispose()... Heres the Code:

```
        var SelectAll =
            (from a in dc.GetTable<SR>()
             select a).ToList();
        int all = SelectAll .Count();

        var ByGroup =
            (from a in dc.GetTable<SR>()
             where a.GroupID == GroupID
             orderby a.ID
             select a).ToList();
        int SelectedGroup = ByGroup .Count();

        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();


        CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar ProgressCircle = new CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar();


        host.Child = ProgressCircle;


        ProgressGrid.Children.Add(host);

        if (ShallMarquee == 1 || FilterByThisDivision == TheEmployee.Division)
        {
            ProgressCircle.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        }
        else
        {
            ProgressCircle.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        }

        ProgressCircle.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 4000;
        ProgressCircle.Text = Convert.ToString(NumOf + "%");
        ProgressCircle.SubscriptText = "";
        ProgressCircle.SuperscriptText = "";
        ProgressCircle.Font = new Font("Arial", 22);
        ProgressCircle.ProgressWidth = 10;
        ProgressCircle.SuperscriptColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        ProgressCircle.ProgressColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(MainColor);
        System.Windows.Media.Color StandardBackgroundBlue = (System.Windows.Media.Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(BackgroundColor);
        var drawingcolor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(StandardBackgroundBlue.A, StandardBackgroundBlue.R, StandardBackgroundBlue.G, StandardBackgroundBlue.B);
        ProgressCircle.BackColor = drawingcolor;
        ProgressCircle.InnerColor = drawingcolor;
        ProgressCircle.OuterColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;

        ProgressCircle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        ProgressCircle.Value = NumOf;
        ProgressCircle.Maximum = TotalNum;
        //END CIRCLE
```

For now the gridjust displays a string as the number while I adjust things so you can ignore that. I also read something about GDI but I'm a bit lost.

P.S. I should note it also says "Invalid Parameter" which it most certainly is not.

P.P.S. I developed this on a Windows 7 64 bit. My laptop is a Windows 10 64bit. But it also doesn't work on my brothers Windows 7 64 bit. If that helps any...

Comment: Have you tried adding the CircularProgressBar control to a quick test Windows Forms app and running in both environments?

Comment: Personally, I would just use a wpf usercontrol and do the animation in wpf. At what point do you get your error? As soon as you start up? I wonder if you're maybe targeting a .net framework version which isn't installed.

Comment: The error occurs at "ProgressGrid.Children.Add(host);". It's in a void function that I call a few times but it occurs at this point every time.

Comment: Hey Andy, I'm not very good at this stuff yet and am still trying to understand it so I'm not sure how to even go about using a wpf usercontrol to do the animation. I did check out what frameworks I had installed.Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the issue. It is developed for 4.5. I have 4.5, and 4.6 on my main developing pc. I went ahead and checked the others I was trying it on and they all have either 4.5 or 4.7. What I do have installed that the others do not is 4.5.1 SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to make it work. I'm not "exactly" sure why though. I loaded the grid that contains the WindowsFormsHost Grid with visibility set to false first and after it loaded I set it to true. For whatever reason, it works this way. If anyone could think of why that would be awesome. This way does work though!